# Probability density function of $Y=\exp(X)$ and $Y=\sqrt{X}$

Tags: probability-distributions

If X has uniform distribution on (0,1), how do I calculate probability density functions of $Y=\exp(X)$ and $Y=\sqrt{X}$?

I can assume the shape of these pdfs when I make histogram of mentioned variables in MATLAB, but i don't know how to calculate exact functions. Can i get some help, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method for the first part of this question seems to be similar to the question addressed in the first part of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278410/finding-the-probability-density-function-of-y-ex-where-x-is-standard-norma).

There, many of the answers suggest finding the CDF (cumulative distribution function) and taking the derivative, which is the PDF (probability distribution function). The CDF of $Y=e^X$ is defined as follows:
$$ F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(e^X \leq y)$$
which is 0 when $y\leq0$, and for y>0 is as follows:
$$ P(e^X \leq y)=P\left(X\leq \ln(y)\right) = F_X(\ln(y))$$
Differentiating $F_X(\ln(y))$ with respect to $y$ to get $f_y(y)$, we obtain the following:
$$ f_y(y) = F'_X(\ln(y))\frac{1}{y}=f_x(\ln(y))\frac{1}{y}$$
Since $X$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,1)$, it has a PDF  of $f_x(x)=1$ for $ 0<x<1$. 
$$ f_x(\ln(y))=1*\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{y}, 0<\frac{1}{y}<1$$
Thus, $f_y(y)=\frac{1}{y}$ for $0<\ln(y)<1$ and $f_y(y)=0$ otherwise.

Similarly for $Y=\sqrt{X}$,
$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(\sqrt{X}\leq y)=P(X\leq y^2)=F_X(y^2)$$ 
Then, differentiating, 
$$ f_y(y)=F'_X(y^2)2y=f_x(y^2)2y $$
Again, since $X$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,1)$, it has a PDF  of $f_x(x)=1$ for $ 0<x<1$.
Then, 
$$ f_x(y^2)=1*2y =2y, 0<y^2<1 $$
Thus, $f_y(y)=2y$ for $0<y^2<1$ and $f_y(y)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Great! Appreciate your help.