# Marginal mass function involving Y=r(X)

Tags: expected-value

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$. Let $Y=r(X)=e^{X}$. Then,
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y)=\int_{0}^{1} e^{x} f(x) d x=\int_{0}^{1} e^{x} d x=e-1
$$
Alternatively, you could find $f_{Y}(y)$ which turns out to be $f_{Y}(y)=1 / y$ for $1<y<e$. Then, $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\int_{1}^{e} y f(y) d y=e-1$.

Question: How does one obtain $1/y$ in computing the marginal mass function of $y$?

Comment: You can use a change of variables, or find $\mathbb P(Y \le y)$ and then differentiate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** $F_Y(y)=P(e^X \leq y)$ will give the CDF and its dericative will give the PDF (probability distribution function)

Try yourself and if you can't do it yourself then refer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2259796/610697)